How to copy SSH private key from Ubuntu to Windows?
I needed Ubuntu on my Windows laptop to work with remote servers, so I installed VMware to run Ubuntu on the same machine.
Now I need to transfer the private key from Ubuntu on VMware to Windows to access the remote server from Windows.
How can I transfer my private key to Windows?

Is there a reason you want to use OpenSSH on Ubuntu instead of OpenSSH built-into Windows? You can even use an Ubuntu WSL instance and run OpenSSH from there. You should be creating a new key for a new user if you’re switching from a Ubuntu user to a Windows user.

@Ramhound Why would a new key be created when there's no security benefit to keeping SSH identities separate provided the SSH key is encrypted with a strong passphrase? This can be further hardened by transfering the SSH key to a hardware key and using GPG to load the key (three incorrect unlock attempts and a YubiKey locks itself and requires a full key erase as part of the unlock process).

I am not sure why you want to do this because establishing a separate ssh identity with ssh_key_gen in the Windows machine will keep the identities separate.
But, here's the info:
In your home directory ($HOME or ~), you will find a hidden subdirectory (.ssh) containing your private ssh key — id_rsa — as well as your public key — id_rsa.pub. This directory also contains a list of known_hosts that list the machines you have logged into with ssh.
The file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys lists the public keys that are permitted for logging in. When the user logs in, the ssh program tells the server which key pair it would like to use for authentication.  The client proves that it has access to the private key and the server checks that the corresponding public key is authorized to accept the account.

There's no security benefit to keeping SSH identities separate provided the SSH key is encrypted with a strong passphrase. This can be further hardened by transfering the SSH key to a hardware key and using GPG to load the key (three incorrect unlock attempts and a YubiKey locks itself and requires a full key erase as part of the unlock process)

You need to copy the following files (your private and public keys) on your Ubuntu machine to your Windows machine.
Ubuntu (source files):
~/.ssh/id_rsa
~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Windows (destination path):
%UserProfile%\.ssh\

